# Trying to change table border, won't change from current size

Tags: html, css

*Warning: I'm literally just beginning to learn HTML/CSS.*

I'm trying to increase the border size of the lower cells. However, when I try to change the size of the border to 2px, it simply stays its current size. Only the outer border.

My end goal is to have the outer border solid 3px, with the inside borders dotted 2px.

```css
td:first-child {
  border-left: 3px solid lightgrey;
  border-right: 2px dotted lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted lightgrey;
}

td {
  border-right: 2px dotted lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted lightgrey;
}

id=cell9 {
  border-bottom: 3px solid lightgrey;
}

id=cell6 {
  border-bottom: 3px solid lightgrey;
}

id=cell3 {
  border-bottom: 3px solid lightgrey;
}

td:last-child {
  border-right: 3px solid lightgrey;
  border-bottom: 2px dotted lightgrey;
}

th:first-child {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
}

th:last-child {
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

tbody tr:last-child td:first-child {
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
}

tbody tr:last-child td:last-child {
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>testing</title>
  <link href="/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
</head>

<body>
  <table style="width:25%">
    <tr id="row1">
      <th id="cell1" bgcolor=lightgrey>Firstname</th>
      <th id="cell2" bgcolor=lightgrey>Lastname</th>
      <th id="cell3" bgcolor=lightgrey>Age</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row2">
      <td id="cell4">Jill</td>
      <td id="cell5">Smith</td>
      <td id="cell6">50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="row3">
      <td id="cell7">Eve</td>
      <td id="cell8">Jackson</d>
        <td id="cell9">94</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Since you seem to understand most of the css targeting rules I think this might be just a simple typeo. But you have instances where you try something like `id=cell9` which doesn't target anything. Should be `#cell9` or `[id=cell9]` if you really want to go attribute selector https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/ID_selectors

Comment: Thank you so much! Changing that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Changed id=cell9, id=cell6, and id=cell3 to #cell7, #cell8 and #cell9.

Answer (score 0):

To help you sort it out, I've had to change your code a bit to reduce extra styles and make styles a bit simpler + maintainable(Look at bigger table which inherited styles completely).

1. I applied solid border + border radius to whole table

```
table {
  border: 3px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

2. Applied background to whole tableheader:

```
th {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
```

3. These 2 styles for dotted borders on cells that go after each other (I've used `+` [selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_element_pluss.asp) to exclude first-child).

```
td+td {
  border-left: 2px dotted lightgrey;
}

tr+tr td {
  border-top: 2px dotted lightgrey;
}
```

Hope this will help you to in further learning! Try to get the idea of such approach, where you are trying to hit the most common selector, to write less individual styles, it will make your code easier to support & extend in future.

```css
table {
  border: 3px solid lightgrey;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

th {
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

td+td {
  border-left: 2px dotted lightgrey;
}

tr+tr td {
  border-top: 2px dotted lightgrey;
}

th,
td {
  padding: 15px;
}

table {
  border-spacing: 0px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:25%">
  <thead id="row1">
    <tr>
      <th id="cell1">Firstname</th>
      <th id="cell2">Lastname</th>
      <th id="cell3">Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr id="row2">
    <td id="cell4">Jill</td>
    <td id="cell5">Smith</td>
    <td id="cell6">50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="row3">
    <td id="cell7">Eve</td>
    <td id="cell8">Jackson</td>
    <td id="cell9">94</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table style="margin-top: 20px">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```